# Creating a native EV3B block

Tags: ev3

I'm trying to create a native block for a hardware sensor. I've got it working pretty well, but can't get it to show up in the "port view" as anything but a sound sensor. I really need the live view of the data the sensor is seeing. Is there an example of how this is done that I could follow?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: you can't.

The EV3 brick detects which type of sensor is plugged in to the ports by examining the electrical characteristics of the sensor<sup>[1](http://python-ev3.org/DcmDriver.html)</sup>. Electrically, all NXT Analog sensors look pretty much the same, so they will all be detected at the LEGO NXT Sound sensor (or possibly the LEGO NXT Light sensor - or a very, very small chance as the LEGO NXT Touch sensor).

So, take @momrobo's advice and write a small program that simulates the built-in port view.

Or, if you are really ambitious you can create an adapter so that the sensor will look like an EV3 type analog sensor instead of an NXT type analog sensor. How do to this would be better suited to a blog post.

Answer (score 1):

instead of the live data on the port view you can make a small program which contain you sensor block and a display block and make you sensor block send its data to the text display block so you've made your own port view.

Answer (score 1):

***You Can't***

EV3 Port view is a simple program 'downloaded as application.
It can only use certain original sensors.

You would have to make your own program. If you want it in the same section, you can use an option called 'download as application'.